# GraphViz and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visualization, graphviz

I woud like to generate graphs using GraphViz and display them on an ASP.NET webpage.
What is the best library to use for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/).

QuickGraph makes it very easy to model graphs, it has [good documentation](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/documentation) and it's dead easy to [export the graph to GraphViz](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Visualization%20Using%20Graphviz&referringTitle=Documentation).

Comment: Agreed, but I've found QuickGraph's DOT-output to be limited and in some cases, buggy.  BUT, using QuickGraph to generate input the graph is convenient, then it is not difficult to custom output a DOT for passing to GraphViz for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following newer object-oriented .NET wrapper: https://github.com/Rubjerg/Graphviz.NetWrapper

It doesn't generate dot files or anything, but performs direct function calls to the underlying DLL, allowing you to do virtually anything you could do when you would have been writing C++ code. I use it myself to render interactive graphs on an ASP.NET webpage.